# Which control is used to hold image,text and audio files like a flow document in windows phone applications

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I am developing an application similar to one-note in windows phone. I wonder what control they use for storing image,text and audio files.

[I tried with RichTextBox but I found that RichTextbox is readonly for windows phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.isreadonly%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Please suggest an approch to achieve this functionality
Thanks in advance.

[For those who are not aware of One-note app in windows it holds text,images and audio 
files like a Flow document.](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/how-to/wp7/office/use-office-onenote-mobile)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use a `<Canvas>`

[MSDN Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.canvas%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

It can hold any other XAML object and they can quickly and easily be positioned on the canvas in both XAML and back end code

That said, you are going to have to do some custom coding to create the UI elements dynamically. 
This shouldn't be to hard.

If it were me I would create an application bar and in the sub menu I would create all of the UI elements you're allowing the person to create. When they select a UIElement it adds it to the canvas and you allow it to be draggable and editable.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried with canvas. But if we use canvas and add controls dynamically. How to store these controls data in a database.How we show user a cursor and edit option when user wants it...I looked into microsoft onenote template. I am looking for that or a similar template could you suggest where could I find one..?

Comment: Getting the data of each control isnt hard... Why cant you just reflect on each UI element and store its property into a dictionary?? Then you can easily iterate through it to save it where ever.